# Change Media Stream ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, mediastream

I am receiving the media stream object from a peer to peer connection. The local stream id seems to be normal; however the remote one always has curly brackets around it.

Is there any way to remove these brackets (I believe that the id inside them is correct)?

Output of local stream object:

`active: true`
`id: "60a521f7-99b5-45f7-b56b-bcdae3e6d19d"`
`onactive: null`
`onaddtrack: null`
`oninactive: null`
`onremovetrack: null`

Output of remote stream object:

`active: true`
`id: "{fee7ee3f-176e-a943-8a4c-25339dfc6ad4}"`
`onactive: null`
`onaddtrack: null`
`oninactive: null`
`onremovetrack: null`

Comment: I've experienced it with FF if I remember it correctly, that's the pattern of the browser.

Comment: Hello from July 2020... I'm having exactly the same problem, the stream ID is definitely correct, but when Firefox sends over the stream ID, it puts brackets around it. (Which, by the way, Safari really hates.) Why does Firefox add brackets?! Can't find anything in any docs.

Answer (score 0):

MediaStream **id** is a readonly property, you can not change its value. Please refer [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#dom-mediastream)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop and resume recording with your webcam, see the logic below.

```
  const toggleCam = (): void => {
    if (playing) {
      const cam = webcamRef.current?.video

      if (cam && cam.srcObject) {
        const stream = cam.srcObject as MediaStream
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
          track.stop()
        })
        setPlaying(!playing)
      }
    } else {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConstraints.deviceSet).then((stream: MediaStream) => {
        if (webcamRef.current?.video) {
          webcamRef.current.video.srcObject = stream
        }
      })
      setPlaying(!playing)
    }
  }
```

This is a toggle button.

```
              <button
                className="flex items-center justify-center w-1/2 px-4 py-2 m-2 text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-700"
                onClick={() => toggleCam()}>
                {playing ? "Stop" : "Start"}{" "}
              </button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).